# Toolbar items flicker on macOS app built with SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, toolbar

I'm implementing a macOS app using latest Xcode *(12.3)* and SwiftUI.

My problem is that **items in toolbars of the app jump around** when UI updates based on user selection in navigation view. This is probably an issue in SwiftUI, but I would like to find a workaround for the issue, since it makes the app feel really broken.

[image: Screenshot explaining the problem]

Toolbar implementation is simplest possible I could come up with:

```
Text("Detail")
        .toolbar {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
            }
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
            }
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "star")
            }
        }
```

Full [source code](https://github.com/taimila/toolbarissueapp/blob/main/ToolbarIssueApp/ContentView.swift) (~60 lines) can be found from my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/taimila/toolbarissueapp) with the [video](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taimila/toolbarissueapp/main/issue.mov) demonstrating the issue better.

I've tried to set explicit frames for the views to mitigate the issue, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Not reproducible on macOS 11.1 Xcode 12.3.

Comment: It looks like this has to do with the toolbar being rerendered every time a list item is selected. You'll notice if you move all of those toolbar items to the List then the issue doesn't occur. Not sure how to fix it though

Comment: @pawello2222 thanks you for the reply. I have macOS 11.2 Beta (20D5029f) and it could be that this issue is specific for the macOS version I have.

Comment: @LauriTaimila did you ever get this figured out for sure? I'm getting the same jitter. Moving all of the toolbar items to the list stops it, but not the detail. Any solutions?

Comment: @jnpdx unfortunately no. I have not found a solution for this that would fix the issue for me. I decided to put my hobby project on hold and wait for WWDC21. Hoping to see bug fixes and new APIs soon.